# Angular - "Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

Tags: angular, laravel, api

I am working on a project having Angular 7 as frontend and Laravel 5.8 as backend. What I want is that when a user (Admin) with id = 1, logs in he sees everything. But when other users log in, he sees only his data which has his user_id.

Laravel: Backend

```
   public function indexSmsmo()
{
if(Auth::user()->id == 1)
     $smsmos = Smsmo::all();
else 
 $smsmos = Smsmo::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id);
return $smsmos;               
}
```

I have user table and other tables. The other tables has user_id in them.

auth.service.ts

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment.prod';
import { User } from '../models/user';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

public currentUser: User;
private readonly apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;
private environmentService: EnvironmentService;

constructor(
private http: HttpClient,
private router: Router) 
{     
}

onLogin(user: User): Observable<User> {

const request = JSON.stringify(
  { email: user.email, password: user.password }
);

return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, request, httpOptions)
  .pipe(
   map((response: User) => {
  // Receive jwt token in the response
  const token: string = response['access_token'];
  // If we have a token, proceed
  if (token) {
    this.setToken(token);
    this.getUser().subscribe();
  }
  return response;
  }),
  catchError(error => this.handleError(error))
   );
  }
```

After this we have login component

login.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
  document.body.className = 'hold-transition login-page';
  $(() => {
  $('input').iCheck({
   checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
   radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
   increaseArea: '20%' /* optional */
  });
});

//  Set the return url
this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/home';
this.authService.onLogout();
}

onSubmit(loginForm): void {
this.spinnerService.show();
this.authService.onLogin(this.user).subscribe(
  (response) => {      

this.notify.success('Done, you have successfully logged in.', {timeout:2000, position: "rightTop"})        
this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);       
},
(error) => {
this.spinnerService.hide();
this.error = error.error;
}
);
 // Clear form fields
 loginForm.reset();
 }
```

When I logged in with userId 1, everything went fine. But when I logged in with other userId I had this error:

> httpErrorResponse message: "Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

If a user logs in and the user_id is 1, he should see everything, but if it is not 1, he should see on data with user_id equals to the login ID

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `index` method, if user is `id === 1`, you return a collection because you used `all()`.

If the user is not `id === 1`, you are only returning a *builder object* because you do not complete the query:

```
$smsmos = Smsmo::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id);
```

should be

```
$smsmos = Smsmo::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first(); // or get() if you want a collection
```

Comment: Am want a collection, so I used:     $smsmos = Smsmo::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->all();       But the error still came.

Comment: Sorry - wasn't thinking you'd need a collection.  The comment should have said `get()`, not all.  `get()` will work for you and remove the error.  So `$smsmos = Smsmo::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();`